# How to avoid an exit confirmation?

Tags: c#, exception, counter, exit, formclosing

what I want to do is simple but I do not know how to do it. I'm doing a basic window login, and I wrote a code to ask for confirmation before exit, like this: (I have the names in spanish, the "Contador" is the counter if you do not understand)

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea cerrar la aplicación?", 
       "Aviso!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    if (dialogo == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

What I've done after that, is a counter that if I entry the incorrect information three times, the application is going to close, here's the code:

```
private int Contador;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contador = 0;
    aceptar.Enabled = false;
    usuario.MaxLength = 40;
    contraseña.MaxLength = 10;            
}    

private void aceptar_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if(Contador == 2)
    {
        DialogoCerrar();
        Close();
    } 
   if (usuario.Text == ("Demo") && (contraseña.Text == ("ABC123")))
    {
        Contador = 0;
        DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show(
          "Ingreso exitoso!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show(
           "Datos incorrectos", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        Contador++;
    }                   
}
```

So, this works, but when after three times I put the incorrect information, before to close the program ask me if I want to do it (I know that is for the **Form1_FormClosing**), and I want that the program doesn't ask it in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a flag:

```
private bool _noConfirmExit;

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_noConfirmExit)
    {
        return;
    }

    DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea cerrar la aplicación?", "Aviso!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    if (dialogo == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void aceptar_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(Contador == 2)
    {
        _noConfirmExit = true;
        DialogoCerrar();
        Close();
    } 

    if (usuario.Text == ("Demo") && (contraseña.Text == ("ABC123")))
    {
        Contador = 0;
        DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("Ingreso exitoso!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        Contador++;
    }
}
```

That way, your `FormClosing` event handler can tell the difference between closing for other reasons and closing because the counter reached its limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that tracks whether you should show the warning dialog box. It's basically a flag that you set when you don't want to show the dialog box.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool SkipWarning = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!SkipWarning)
            {
                DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea cerrar la aplicación?", "Aviso!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                if (dialogo == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void aceptar_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if(Contador == 2)
        {
            SkipWarning = true;
            DialogoCerrar();
            Close();
        } 
       if (usuario.Text == ("Demo") && (contraseña.Text == ("ABC123")))
        {
            Contador = 0;
            DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("Ingreso exitoso!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogo = MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            Contador++;
        }                   
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you too! The logic is a bit different that Duniho, but is another similar way, tank you again!